# Adding a mimetype in python

Tags: python, mime-types

On my Centos server Python's mimetypes.guess_type("mobile.3gp") returns (None, None), instead of ('video/3gpp', None).

Where does Python get the list of mimetypes from, and is it possible to add a missing type to the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my system (Debian lenny) its in /usr/lib/python2.5/mimetypes.py
in the list `knownfiles` you can supply your own files for the `init()` function.

Comment: Something I usually forget and that does not cause an error is passing just a simple string with a file path to init().  init() expects a list of file paths.

Answer (score 2):

The mimetypes module uses mime.types files as they are common on Linux/Unix systems. If you look in mimetypes.knownfiles you will find a list of files that Python tries to access to load the data. You can also specify your own file to add new types by adding it to that list.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.6 find that file: `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\mimetypes.py`

Search for `mp3` (to get the list of extension). Add your file (it's intuitive)